# How to I pluralize in php?

Tags: php

Ok so i have this chunk of code

```
<p id="number_of_stations" class="text left"><?php $_GET['count'] != "" ? print "{$_GET['count']} Stations" : print "Number of Stations" ?></p>
```

and $_GET['count'] will be either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 and i need to print out the following

```
1 Station
2 Stations
3 Stations
4 Stations
5 Stations
```

but the code i have above will always print the plural form and not the singular

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplified:

```
echo "$count Station" . ($count == 1 ? null : 's');
```

You may want to create a function for this if you're using this often. If you're looking for automagic pluralization of any word you'll need to write an [Inflector](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/inflector).

Comment: Actually, a better way is `($count!=1 ? 's' : "")` that way it will do *0 stations* instead of *0 station*

Answer (score 3):

On this simple case you can just add an `s` at the end (see deceze's answer), but if you want a true `pluralize()` method that can handle irregular forms (eg: 1 box, 2 boxes; 1 person, 2 people, etc)  then there's nothing built-in.

You'll have to write your own class/method, or use one available on the Internets.
Here's an implementation: http://blog.eval.ca/2007/03/03/php-pluralize-method/

Comment: One of the awesome parts of Rails. `pluralize( 3, 'person') == "3 people"`

Comment: @webdestroya [Many](http://book.cakephp.org/view/491/Inflector) [PHP](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/inflector_helper.html) [frameworks](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.plurals.html) have an `Inflector` class (or similar) that does the same thing

Comment: @MitchDempsey What Rails has to do with PHP (see OP's question)?

Comment: @trejder nothing, that's why it's a comment and not the answer. And also why it's 13 years ago...